# ResponsEentityExceptionHandler: handleMethodArgumentNotValid Not Intercepted

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception

My controller has the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void save(@RequestBody @Valid final User resource) {
    createInternal(resource);
}
```

Because of the @Valid before the resource parameter, I expect it to be intercepted by the following exception handler when I pass in a `NULL` into a `nullable=false` on my @Column of my entity,

```
@Override
protected final ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(final MethodArgumentNotValidException e,                                     
                                                                    final HttpHeaders headers, 
                                                                    final HttpStatus status, 
                                                                    final WebRequest request) {
    log.info("Bad Request: {}", ex.getMessage());
    log.debug("Bad Request: ", ex);

    ...

    return handleExceptionInternal(e, dto, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
}
```

But it seems I can only handle it this way instead:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { ConstraintViolationException.class,  
                            DataIntegrityViolationException.class })
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadRequest(final RuntimeException e,
                                                     final WebRequest request) {
    ...
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, apiError, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
}
```

Why isn't the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` exception handler picking it up like it should?

Answer (score 1):

Before your 'handleMethodArgumentNotValid' has a chance to fire, DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handles this

or if you want to handle declare , `@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)`

> An @RequestBody method parameter can be annotated with @Valid, in
>   which case it will be validated using the configured Validator
>   instance. When using the MVC namespace or the MVC Java config, a
>   JSR-303 validator is configured automatically assuming a JSR-303
>   implementation is available on the classpath.
>
> Just like with @ModelAttribute parameters, an Errors argument can be
>   used to examine the errors. If such an argument is not declared, a
>   MethodArgumentNotValidException will be raised. The exception is
>   handled in the DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver, which sends a 400
>   error back to the client. Before your 'handleMethodArgumentNotValid'
>   has a chance to fire, this is handndf

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody

Comment: I was not annotating my column with the "@NotNull" annotation on my entity, therefore, the "@Valid" was not working. I had the "@Column(nullable = false)", but it didn't catch this way

Answer (score -1):

> Why isn't the handleMethodArgumentNotValid exception handler picking
>   it up like it should?

Spring container (during start up) scans through all of the controller(s) methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` and `@ExceptionHandler`.

Later, when the request comes with an `url`, the controller method will be identified using `handlermapping`, then injects all the required dependencies (controller method arguments) like `Model`, `HttpRequest`, etc.. and delegates the call the controller method to serve the input request.

Since your `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` is not annotated with either `@RequestMapping` or `@ExceptionHandler`, Spring container can't recognise this method.

Comment: This answer is total bollocks. It's regarding an overridden handler. Annotating it twice causes an error when the application is being wired. 'Ambiguous Exception Handler'.

Answer (score -1):

```
@ExceptionHandler({ ConstraintViolationException.class })
public ResponseEntity<> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex, 
    WebRequest request) {
    // error handeling

    return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

More details at https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api